# Jenkins remote file operation failure

Tags: jenkins

I am setting up a slave Jenkins server on a RHEL 6 box Jenkins 1.605 on the master server.

I created a jenkins_user account

I setup a folder for Jenkins to do work in in /var/jenkins this is owned by jenkins_user and /var was recursively chmoded to 777.

I launch the following deamon

```
echo -n $"Starting Jenkins Build Slave: "
su jenkins_user sh -c "java -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:+UseConcMarkSweep\
GC  -jar /jenkins_slave/slave.jar -jnlpUrl http://master:8080/path/on/slave/to/slave-agent.jnlp -jnlpCredentials credentials_here > /var/jenkins/save.log 2>&1 &"

echo Done
```

I get the following failure:

> 08:43:05 RTC : checkout... 08:43:07 FATAL: RTC : checkout failure:
>   remote file operation failed: /var/jenkins/workspace/project at
>   hudson.remoting.Channel@3c7d5fe4:slave_server.com:
>   java.io.IOException: Remote call on slave_server.com failed

When I run the deamon as root instead everything works.

any ideas?

Comment: Try `su jenkins_user bash -lc "java ... "`.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the suggestion su jenkins_user bash -lc ...

I received an error that the home/jenkins_user directory did not exist (which it didn't)

I deleted and recreated the user to regenerate the home/jenkins_user directory and it worked.

Whether the solution was the suggested fix or just the repair for the jenkins_user IDK but it works now.